# Django is not showing the right path when clicking on a link

Tags: django, url, http-status-code-404

**This is what it shows when you click on the link**

> Page not found (404)
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://localhost:8000/jobapplication/new/1
>
> Using the URLconf defined in careal.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:
>
> ^$ [name='landing-index']
>
> ^admin/
>
> ^accounts/
>
> ^taskmanager/
>
> ^login/$ [name='login']

- The problem is that I don't know why it is opening the link as http://localhost:8000/jobapplication/new/1, when it should be http://localhost:8000/taskmanager/jobapplication/new/1
- This is what I have in the urls.py

  ```
  from django.conf.urls import include, url
      from django.contrib import admin
      from django.conf import settings
      from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
      from landingpage import views as landingpage_views

  urlpatterns = [
          url(r'^$', landingpage_views.index, name='landing-index'),
          url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
          url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
          url(r'^taskmanager/', include('taskmanager.urls')),
          url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
  ]
  ```
- This is in urls.py in the app taskmanager

  ```
  from django.conf.urls import url
  from . import views
  from taskmanager.views import *

  app_name = 'taskmanager'
  urlpatterns = [
   # Task manager urls
     url(r'^$', JobApplicationIndex.as_view(), name='index'),
     url(r'jobapplication/add/(?P<jobpost_id>[0-9]+)/$', JobApplicationCreate.as_view(), name='jobapplication-add'),
     url(r'jobapplication/new/(?P<jobpost_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.JobApplicationAdd, name='jobapplication-new'),
     url(r'jobapplication/edit/(?P<jobpost_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.JobApplicationEdit, name='jobapplication-edit'),
    url(r'jobapplication/edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', JobApplicationUpdate.as_view(), name='jobapplication-edit'),
    url(r'^jobapplication/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', JobApplicationDetails.as_view(), name='jobapplication-detail'),

  # Company urls
  url(r'company/$', CompanyIndex.as_view(), name='company-index'),
  url(r'company/add/$', CompanyCreate.as_view(), name='company-add'),
  url(r'^company/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', CompanyDetails.as_view(), name='company-detail'),

  # Job Post urls
  url(r'jobpost/$', JobPostIndex.as_view(), name='jobpost-index'),
  url(r'^jobpost/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', JobPostDetails.as_view(), name='jobpost-detail'),

  # Statistics urls
  url(r'^kpi/$', views.kpi, name='kpi'),
  ]
  ```
- And this is what I have in views.py in taskmanager, related to jobapplication

  ```
  # Job Application views
  class JobApplicationIndex(generic.ListView):
  template_name = 'taskmanager/jobapplication_index.html'

  def get_queryset(self):
      if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
          return   JobApplication.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id).order_by('-created_at')


  class JobApplicationCreate(CreateView):
  model = JobApplication
  fields = ['jobpost', 'sent_date', 'deadline', 'success_rate']

  def get_initial(self):
      jobpost = get_object_or_404(JobPost,  id=self.kwargs.get('jobpost_id'))
      return {
          'jobpost':jobpost,
      }

  def form_valid(self, form):
      form.instance.user = self.request.user
      return super(JobApplicationCreate, self).form_valid(form)

  class JobApplicationDetails(generic.DetailView):
  model = JobApplication

  class JobApplicationEdit(UpdateView):
  model = JobApplication
  #fields = ['jobpostid', 'is_favorite']
  #p = JobApplication.objects.get(id=jobpostid)
  #p.is_favorite = is_favorite
  #p.save()


  class JobApplicationUpdate(UpdateView):
  model = JobApplication
  fields = ['sent_date', 'deadline', 'success_rate']
  template_name_suffix = '_update_form'


  def JobApplicationAdd(request, jobpost_id):
   if request.method == 'GET' and request.user.is_authenticated:
      # If job app for this id exists, redirect to that job app page with a message
      if JobApplication.objects.filter(jobpost_id=int(jobpost_id)).exists():
          existing = JobApplication.objects.get(jobpost_id=int(jobpost_id))
          messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'An application for this opening already exists.')
          return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('taskmanager:jobapplication-detail', args=[existing.id]))

      jobapp = JobApplication(user=request.user, jobpost_id=int(jobpost_id), success_rate=50)
      jobapp.save()

  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('taskmanager:index'))
  ```

**--- The thing is all the other links in taskmanager work and when you click on them, the right path is opened Eg: -**

```
  - http://localhost:8000/taskmanager/jobpost/
  - http://localhost:8000/taskmanager/jobpost/2/
  - http://localhost:8000/taskmanager/company/2/
  - http://localhost:8000/taskmanager/kpi/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding an uptick in front of the regex patterns like you did for the ones that are working.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from taskmanager.views import *

app_name = 'taskmanager'
urlpatterns = [
    # Task manager urls
    url(r'^$', JobApplicationIndex.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^jobapplication/add/(?P<jobpost_id>[0-9]+)/$', JobApplicationCreate.as_view(), name='jobapplication-add'),
    url(r'^jobapplication/new/(?P<jobpost_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.JobApplicationAdd, name='jobapplication-new'),
    url(r'^jobapplication/edit/(?P<jobpost_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.JobApplicationEdit, name='jobapplication-edit'),
    url(r'^jobapplication/edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', JobApplicationUpdate.as_view(), name='jobapplication-edit'),
    url(r'^jobapplication/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', JobApplicationDetails.as_view(), name='jobapplication-detail'),

    # Company urls
    url(r'^company/$', CompanyIndex.as_view(), name='company-index'),
    url(r'^company/add/$', CompanyCreate.as_view(), name='company-add'),
    url(r'^company/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', CompanyDetails.as_view(), name='company-detail'),

    # Job Post urls
    url(r'^jobpost/$', JobPostIndex.as_view(), name='jobpost-index'),
    url(r'^jobpost/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', JobPostDetails.as_view(), name='jobpost-detail'),

    # Statistics urls
    url(r'^kpi/$', views.kpi, name='kpi'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried that before but I still got the same results.